# IText setFixedHeight

Tags: java, itext

Good Morning,
We recently migrated from iText version 5.4.3 to iText version 5.5.9.  The code we're using to add text to the PdfPCell doesn't looks like it's honoring the setFixedHeight.  Has anything changed on this that would not truncate overflow text?  I'd give a code example, but we're just creating a table, adding a row/cell and setting the fixedheight on the cell which works in version 5.4.3.

Thanks for your help,
-Jeff

Comment: if you migrate anyways, is there a reason why you font do so to the current 5.5.x?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was just trying to match version with another one of our projects.  I did just try 5.5.13 and looks like I'm getting the same issue.  The setFixedHeight is not getting honored.

Comment: In that case please supply example code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using methods of `PdfPCell`, like below

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
cell.setPadding(0);
cell.setPaddingTop(10);
```